# How do I perma-stop Chrome from using it's own DNS across the enterprise?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, google-chrome

When attempting to access an intranet site, Chrome will ignore our DNS settings and navigate to a public page.

Our computers are referencing only our private DNS server. Last week, I disabled built-in DNS and DoH in Google Workspace Admin (Devices/Chrome/Settings/Users & Browsers) as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xCc6.png), and that rule is applied at the top most level, with no overrides at lower levels. That being said, another user of mine just experienced the issue again.

How do I permaban, enterprise-wide, Chrome's alternate routes for DNS?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem persists (just like in my case), you have to disable some flags:
Navigate to edge://flags/ or chrome://flags/.
Disable #use-dns-https-svcb-alpn.
Disable #enable-async-dns (Chrome only).
Disable #encrypted-client-hello (Chrome only).

Source: https://www.bugdrivendevelopment.net/browser-ignore-internal-dns/